# checkbox value still false even when checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox

checkbox in my form is unchecked by default and send a false value to the database but suprisingly even when checked ,still insert false value still, i was expecting by checking it will give it a value 1 thus true, what am i missing here? Thank you.

```
<%= form_for @book, :url=>{:action =>"create"} do |c| %>
  <%= c.check_box  :active %>
  <%= c.text_field :username %>
<% end %>

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Comment: add your model with this question

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box may help you

Comment: Also, please include the actual params being passed from the log entry. It's possible you've got a param name mismatch, meaning the data from the form is getting to the controller, but is being misinterpreted.

Comment: In the parameter shows `active=>"0"` which means is not checked while i checked it

Comment: What does the generated html look like when the form is in the unchecked state?